# Order of Initializer list in C++

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I understand that for non-static members variables, order of evaluation in the initializer list is according to the order of declaration in the class.

Consider below example from isocpp

```
#include <iostream>

class Y {
   public:
      Y();
      void f();
};

Y::Y()      { std::cout << "Initializing Y\n"<<this<<"\n"; }

void Y::f() { std::cout << "Using Y\n"<<this<<"\n"; }

class X {
   public:
      X(Y& y);
};

X::X(Y& y) { y.f(); }

class Z {
   public:
      Z() throw();
   protected:
      X x_;
      Y y_;
};

Z::Z() throw() : y_(), x_(y_) {}

int main()
{
   Z z;
   return 0;
}
```

As X's ctor requires Y's reference we must ideally initialize y_ first; which means y_ has to be declared before x_.

I expected above program to give seg fault but below is my o/p. Can someone put some light on this.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
Using Y
0x7fffffffe0c1
Initializing Y
0x7fffffffe0c1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> class Z {
>    public:
>       Z() throw();
>    protected:
>       X x_;
>       Y y_;
> };
>
> Z::Z() throw() : y_(), x_(y_) {}
> ```

In `Z`, you declare `x_` before `y_`.  Therefore, `x` is constructed before `y_` regardless of the order of your initializers.

And, initializing `x_(y_)` before `y_` is constructed yields undefined behavior.

---

> I expected above program to give seg fault

Undefined behavior is undefined.  You should not expect anything in particular.

Comment: - Undefined behavior is undefined. You should not expect anything in particular. Understood, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I expected above program to give seg fault but below is my o/p.

In theory your code is subject to undefined behavior.

Space has been allocated for the object but it has not been initialized. Such objects and pointers to such objects can be used in limited ways but calling a non-static member function on such an object is cause for undefined behavior.

From https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.life#5:

> The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> (5.1)
>   the object will be or was of a class type with a non-trivial destructor and the pointer is used as the operand of a delete-expression,
>
> (5.2)
>   the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object, or

The most likely reason why you don't see any bad behavior is that `Y` does not have any member variables. If you add a member variable to `Y` and use it in `Y:f()`, you will most likely notice the problem more readily.

Comment: No UB. Just smelly.. The `y` never undergoes the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, but its storage is already allocated. The pointer/reference is never misused by the op. Accessing a member would violate the contract however.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I was under the impression that calling a member function on an uninitialized object is cause for undefined behavior.

Comment: So was I. Then I read a defect report that wondered why it isn't explicit in the standard. Ultimately, it depends on accessing the object. I get that you'd want to verify rather than just taking my word for it. I'll try to find it.

Comment: @StoryTeller, that will be great but I still take your word for it.

Comment: @R Sahu . Adding a variable and displaying it in the ctor is working too.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour due to calling the member function (C++17 basic.life/7.2)

Comment: @M.M, From https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.life#5: *Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated38 or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that refers to the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways.*

Comment: @M.M, please ignore that. RIght below that, I see: *the program has undefined behavior if: ... the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object, or*

Comment: It means, when object of Z is created, space is allocated for y_. However is it not initialized, now when we try to call f() it results in UB.